# close a AlertDialog after submit a TextField | Flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I got an AlertDialog with a TextField in it. If I submit my TextField I want the AlertDialog to pop off/ vanish.
I tried to add `() => Navigator.of(context).pop()` to my `void on_submitted`, but it does not close the AlertDialog :(

I´m pretty new to flutter and teaching myself to program, so please have some indulgence.

```
      showDialog<CupertinoAlertDialog>(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Gib den Spieler-Namen ein:',
             style: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 15,
              fontFamily: 'ConcertOne'
            ),),
              backgroundColor: Colors.blue[300],
              content: Form(
                key: formKey,
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: msgControllerClassic,
                  onFieldSubmitted: (String txt) => addSpieler(txt),
                  validator: (String value) {
                    if (value.isEmpty) { return 'Du hast nichts eingegeben';}
                    return null;
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          });
  }

void addSpieler(String player) {
    setState(() {
      if (formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      clearTextClassic();
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    }});
  }

AlertDialog is opend by a button-click. I now want the AlertDialog to vanish when submitting (addSpieler)
```

Comment: Can you share some code? Probably you're using the wrong `context`.

Comment: Sorry, updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see your `addSpieler` function, but I'll assume that you are calling `Navigator.of(context).pop()` inside it. Just correct me and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Note that, in `showDialog`, there is a `builder` parameter of type `Widget Function(BuildContext)`. Every time you want to operate on the dialog context, you should use the context provided by this parameter. You can refactor your code as follows:

```dart
showDialog<CupertinoAlertDialog>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      // ...
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: msgControllerClassic,
        // Use the context provided by builder here
        onFieldSubmitted: (String txt) => addSpieler(context, txt),
        validator: (String value) {
          if (value.isEmpty) { return 'Du hast nichts eingegeben';}
            return null;
        },
      ),
    );
  });
);
```

Also refactor your `addSpieler` method:

```dart
void addSpieler(BuildContext context, String txt) {
  // ...
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, not only for the solution but for the explanation, too :)